# Is using "for too much" correct in this case?

Tags: grammaticality, formal-language

Writing thoughts in English, I was compelled to put:

> He is reacting to this for too much.

Even though it seemed natural to me to use *for too much* (based on my experience of learning English), I was not completely sure whether I should use *too much* or *for too much*.

My questions:
1. Is usage of *for too much* grammatically correct in my case?
2. If answer to "1" is "yes", is *for too much* interchangeable with *too much*?
3. If answer to "1" is "yes", can *for too much* be used in formal writing?

Research done before asking:
1. Google gave no relevant informaiton in response to *"too much" and "for too much"* and *"too much" grammar*
2. SkELL has 23 entries of *for too much*, although it seems that *for* in these cases belongs not to *too much*.
[image: SkELL results for too much]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you say, in all of your corpus examples the object of *for* is not *too much* but the noun (either explicit, or implicitly 'fused' with *much* when *much* is employed as a pronoun) which adjectival/quantifier *too much* modifies.

You are seeking to use *too much* as an adverbial modifying *is reacting*; in this use there is no call for a preposition. You want to say:

> He is reacting to this too much.

The use of *for* here may have been suggested to you by an imprecise memory of ***far*** too much, in which *far* is employed as an adverb modifying *too much*.

Note, however, that we do not ordinarily measure the intensity of a reaction as a quantity, which *much* implies. The most common measure is "strength":

> He is reacting to this too strongly *or* too weakly.

Answer (score 0):

> He is reacting to this **for** too much.

That's wrong, since "for too much" describes something, and that sentence doesn't.  It can be rewritten, "He is reacting to this **much** (or **way** or **far**) too much."